# linux mint 17 root password recover

Tags: linux, passwords, root, linux-mint, recover

I got an old x86 laptop with Linux Mint 17 installed. However, I do not have any decent passwords for either root or user accounts.

I have already done steps explained at https://www.tecmint.com/reset-forgotten-root-password-in-linux-mint/. However, after booting it asks the maintenance (root) password which should be a new one, but it does not accept any attemps.

Anyone else has faced this?